# Get user information from social media links

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, youtube-api, flickr

I have social site links of user and i want to access information from these link

```
https://www.facebook.com/username
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/user-name
https://twitter.com/user-name
http://www.youtube.com/user/user-name
http://www.flickr.com/photos/user-name
```

i want to access information without user logging in

Comment: So what is you question here? Read the according docs and you'll find out how that can be done.

Comment: is it possible that i can fetch user information without user login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Facebook**

Without login you can fetch the limited information using the **username**. Since for the rest you have to ask permission from the user and for that you have to implement the facebook login.

You can use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) to get the info-

```
http://graph.facebook.com/username
```

To get the profile picture-

```
http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture
```

**Youtube**

You can use the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started)

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<username>/uploads?v=2&alt=json
```

Similarly you can search for the other APIs..

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works for me. do you have any idea regarding twitter, wikipedia, youtube and flickr

Comment: I've used youtube api (thats quite straight away) but for the rest i'm not aware.